# Finding all keys in a dictionary for which one or more value is repeated more than once in another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries:

```
dict_1 = {'mother': ['mother', 'mom', 'mum', 'mommy', 'mummy', 'mamma', 'momma', 'ma', 'mama'], 
           'boy': ['boy', 'guy', 'dude', 'lad', 'son', 'schoolboy', 'young man'], 
           'girl': ['girl', 'daughter', 'lass', 'schoolgirl', 'young lady'],
           'kitchen': ['kitchen'], 
           'exterior': ['exterior', 'outside', 'outdoor', 'outdoors'],
           'car': ['car', 'vehicule', 'automobile'],
           'water': ['water']
          }

dict_2 = {'basket': 2,
          'car' : 8,
          'juice': 1,
          'window': 6,
          'outside': 2,
          'oudoor': 4,
          'road': 1,
          'mom': 5,
          'mother': 2,
          'song': 1,
          'vehicule': 1,
          'fruits': 6
         }
```

I'm looking for a way to find all keys in dict_1 for which one or more value is a key that has a value > 1 in dict_2 and the number of times a value associated with these keys is repeated in dict_2. Once I've found this, I would like to get another dictionary in which the keys are dict_1's keys (in this case, 'mother' and 'exterior') that are repeated more than once and the values are the number of times a value associated with these keys is repeated in dict_2 (in this case, 7 for 'mother' and 6 for 'exterior').

With the dictionaries I have, I would like my new dictionary to look something like this:

```
dict_final = {'mother': 7,
              'exterior': 6,
              'car': 9
             }
```

Is there a way to do that in Python?

Comment: Why mother has `7` ?

Comment: This question is a bit too open ended. `for key in dict_2.keys():` will get you started. See what you can come up with on your own and edit your question if you run into issues.

Comment: because in dict_2, you have 'mother': 5 as a key, value pair and 'mom': 2 as another key, value pair. Since both mother and mom are values of the key 'mother' in dict_1, you add their values in dict_2 and get 7

Comment: So why is car not in the output?

Comment: @DaniMesejo you're right, I'll edit it

Answer (score 1):

One approach:

```
res = {}
for k, vs in dict_1.items():
    total = sum(dict_2.get(v, 0) for v in vs)
    if total > 0:
        res[k] = total

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
{'mother': 7, 'exterior': 6, 'car': 9}
```

As an alternative consider a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-dictionary-comprehension) (with a [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) in the mix):

```
res = {k: total for k, vs in dict_1.items() if (total := sum(dict_2.get(v, 0) for v in vs)) > 0}
```